# How to make spring boot websocket client works with SSL/TLS?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, stomp, spring-websocket

My code works perfectly with WS: connection, but it doesn't work when I include my SSL certificate.
Let me explain the cenario. When someone sends a message over the internet it reaches my webhook and my webhook sends that message to my websocket. Unfortunately, when I use SSL my java code doesn't work with SSl. The best approach I had was this messa "Unable to create SSLEngine to support SSL/TLS connections" EX2.

EX1 - This code works fine with WS/http

```
private static WebSocketSessionHandler CLIENTONESESSIONHANDLER = new WebSocketSessionHandler();

    public StompSession stompConnection() {

        StompSession session = null;

        try {

            StandardWebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
            WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
            stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
            CompletableFuture<StompSession> sessionAsync = stompClient
                    .connectAsync("ws://localhost:8433/websocket-server", CLIENTONESESSIONHANDLER);

            session = sessionAsync.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return session;
    }

    public void sendMessageToWebSocket(GenericMessageDto obj) {
        StompSession session = stompConnection();
        session.subscribe("/topic/message", CLIENTONESESSIONHANDLER);
        session.send("/app/process-message", obj);
    }


public class WebSocketSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return OutgoingMessage.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + ((OutgoingMessage) payload).getContent());
    }

}
```

EX2

```
    private static WebSocketSessionHandler CLIENTONESESSIONHANDLER = new WebSocketSessionHandler();

    public StompSession stompConnection() {

        StompSession session = null;

        try {

            String websocketUrl = "wss://localhost:8443/websocket-server";

            StandardWebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();

            Map<String, Object> userProperties = new HashMap<>();
            userProperties.put("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_CONTEXT", SSLContext.getDefault());
            userProperties.put("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_PROTOCOLS", SSLContext.getDefault());
            userProperties.put("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_TRUSTSTORE", SSLContext.getDefault());
            client.setUserProperties(userProperties);
            WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
            stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

            session = stompClient.connectAsync(websocketUrl, CLIENTONESESSIONHANDLER, sslSocketFactory, container, sslContext).get();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return session;
    }

    public void sendMessageToWebSocket(GenericMessageDto dto) {
        StompSession session = stompConnection();
        session.subscribe("/topic/message", CLIENTONESESSIONHANDLER);
        session.send("/app/process-message", dto);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.
Fisrt of all you need to add the trust store file and key store file.
Have a look here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate

Load the keystore using a special class Keystore as exampl below.
When using SSl we need to get the instace: SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

Just remember to change this ""wss://:5000/websocket-server" for your website url. It is not going to work if you write down "localhost" nor your IP address because SSL.
I wrote a method as a connection and returning a session and then I do the subcribe like this:

```
public void updateWebsocket() {
    StompSession session = stompConnectionTLS();
    session.subscribe("/topic/messages", CLIENT_SESSION_HANDLER);
    session.send("/app/process", true);
    session.disconnect();
}


public StompSession stompConnectionTLS() {

    StompSession session = null;

    String websocketUrl = "wss://<yourURL>:5000/websocket-server";

    try {

        String trustStoreFile = "/Path/cert.jks";
        String trustStorePassword = "Password";
        String keyStoreFile = "/Path/keystore.p12";
        String keyStorePassword = "Password";

        // Load the trust store
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(trustStoreFile), trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        // Load the key store
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

        StandardWebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        webSocketClient.setUserProperties(Collections.singletonMap("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.SSL_CONTEXT", sslContext));

        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(webSocketClient);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        session = stompClient.connectAsync(websocketUrl, CLIENTSESSIONHANDLER).get();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return session;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

#### Enable SSL/TLS using Spring Boot application properties

SSL/TLS can be enabled using the Spring Boot application properties. Once your create an SSL/TLS certificate, you should adjust your application properties file appropriately:

```yaml
server:
  ssl:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: 'path/to/keystore-file.p12'
    key-store-password: <password>
    key-alias: <your-key-alias>
    enabled: true
```

And that's it! You are now allowed to connect only using `wss://` scheme instead of `ws://`.

You can read more about that here:

- Last section in "Spring Boot + WebSocket + OAuth 2.0 + TLS": https://medium.com/@HereAndBeyond/bf479327339f
- TLS Setup in Spring: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tls-setup

Comment: I've done that too. But the problem was with the Websocket connection.

Comment: When yopu change to "wss" the Websocket stops working for connections from java. The idea is to receive some webhook data and send them through websocket. Thanks for the tip.